# identifying mega bloks parts, including a lot of big fig parts

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Morning all,

I have got a massive box of mega bloks, but am really struggling to find what sets they are from. I have tried to find the more obscure bits so it can hopefully narrow things a bit.

#1
[image]

#2
[image]

#3
[image]

#4
[image]

#5
[image]

#6
[image]

#7
[image]

Comment: Have you already run those blocks through any block sites?

Answer (score 6):

The part on the 1st photo is from MEGABLOKS set 9728 :Blue Thunder
[image]
Source : [Partlist from Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1053889/Mega-Bloks-Model-Max-Blue-Thunder-9728.html?page=2#manual)

I think the part on photo # 2 is from MEGABLOKS set 1401: Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles 1/4 pipe fight
[image]

The raised base plate on the 3th photo is from the Megabloks Dragon line

The part on photo #4 is from
MEGABLOKS set # 9337 Transforming Blok-Bots - Spy
[image]

The brown arm  is from
MEGABLOKS set# 9358 : Transforming Blok-Bots - Gladiator & Lion
[image]